# Symfony DependencyInjection class cannot be declared because the name is already in use

Tags: compiler-errors, symfony5, hexagonal-architecture, symfony-dependency-injection

I created a new symfony 5.3 project. I'm developing this app using hexagonal architecture.

I added a Bundle I developed for another symfony project. This bundle is working in the original project. But in the new project I get the following error:

> ```
> !!  Fatal error: Cannot declare class UserBundle\Infrastructure\DependencyInjection\MycompanyUserExtension, because the name is already in use in /var/www/html/src/Mycompany/UserBundle/Infrastructure/DependencyInjection/MycompanyUserExtension.php on line 11
> !!  Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError {#419
> !!    -error: array:4 [
> !!      "type" => 64
> !!      "message" => "Cannot declare class UserBundle\Infrastructure\DependencyInjection\MycompanyUserExtension, because the name is already in use"
> !!      "file" => "/var/www/html/src/Mycompany/UserBundle/Infrastructure/DependencyInjection/MycompanyUserExtension.php"
> !!      "line" => 11
> !!    ]
> !!    #message: "Compile Error: Cannot declare class UserBundle\Infrastructure\DependencyInjection\MycompanyUserExtension, because the name is already in use"
> !!    #code: 0
> !!    #file: "./src/Mycompany/UserBundle/Infrastructure/DependencyInjection/MycompanyUserExtension.php"
> !!    #line: 11
> !!  }
> ```

the folder structure is:

```
src
  |- Mycompany
     |- UserBundle
        |- MycompanyUserBundle.php
        |- Domain
        |- Infrastructure
           |- DependencyInjection
           |  |- MycompanyUserExtension.php
           |- Resources
              |- config
                 |- routes.yaml
                 |- services.yaml
```

And the code of MycompanyUserBundle is:

```
# src/Mycompany/UserBundle/MycompanyUserBundle.php
namespace UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use UserBundle\Infrastructure\DependencyInjection\MycompanyUserExtension;

class MycompanyUserBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getContainerExtension()
    {
        if (null === $this->extension) {
            $this->extension = new MycompanyUserExtension();
        }
        return $this->extension;
    }
}
```

And the code of MycompanyUserExtension is:

```
# src/Mycompany/UserBundle/Infrastructure/DependencyInjection/MycompanyUserExtension.php
namespace UserBundle\Infrastructure\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;

class MycompanyUserExtension extends Extension
{

    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yaml');
    }

    public function getAlias()
    {
        return 'user_bundle';
    }

}
```

The namespace UserBundle is declared in the composer.json

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "UserBundle\\": "src/Mycompany/UserBundle",
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
```

And the bundle is also declared in the config/bundles.php as `UserBundle\MycompanyUserBundle::class => ['all' => true],`

The bundle is also referenced in config/packages/doctrine.yaml under mappings

```
UserBundle:
  is_bundle: false
  type: annotation
  dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Mycompany/UserBundle/Domain/Entity'
  prefix: 'UserBundle\Domain\Entity'
  alias: UserBundle
```

The `MycompanyUserExtension` is declared only in the same file the error says it is in use, I do not find any duplicated declaration of this class. But the project is not compiling because there is an error. It's a fresh new project without any code or bundle yet.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found the problem. In the config/services.yaml I have declared the UserBundle\ before the App, and my bundle is inside the src folder. So It was reading UserBundle twice.

I declared:

```
UserBundle\:
    resource: '../src/Mycompany/UserBundle/'
    exclude:
        - '../src/Mycompany/UserBundle/Domain/Entity/'
        - '../src/Mycompany/UserBundle/Infrastructure/DependencyInjection/'

App\:
    resource: '../src/'
    exclude:
        - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
        - '../src/Entity/'
        - '../src/Kernel.php'
        - '../src/Tests/'
```

So I only had to exclude the `Mycompany` folder in the App/ declaration

```
- '../src/Mycompany/'
```